# Extract an elliptic curve public key from an EVP_PK structure

Tags: c++, openssl

I have the following code:

```
        auto pbio = BIO_new_mem_buf(static_cast< void const * >(src.data()),
                                    static_cast< int >(src.size()));
        BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(&)
        {
            BIO_free_all(pbio);
        };

        ptr_ = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(pbio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

What I would now like to do is:

1. extract the public key to a new EVP_PKEY structure.
2. encode the public key in PEM format

It's not entirely clear to me from the documentation how I would do this.

Would anyone be able to help with couple of lines of code in order to guide me?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do the first? You should be table to export the public key straight from the private key pointer.

Comment: Because I don't know how to!